# How to map over sequence of Java methods to be executed

Tags: clojure

The following will work:

```
(map #(%1 "21") [identity])
```

However the following code fails

```
(map #(%1 "21") [.toString])
```

How do I create a seq/collection of Java methods?

Comment: You've got the answer, but I'm mostly concerned with the use cases that led you to ask the question. I can't seem to find one. I'd rather `comp` them together to build a function to execute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Java methods are not first class citizens like functions in clojure. You can't pass java methods as parameters, return or store in variables and collections. But you can create function by [memfn](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/memfn) or just anonymous function which wraps original method call

```
(map #(%1 21) [(memfn toString)])
=> ("21")

(map #(%1 21) [#(.toString %)])
=> ("21")
```